# Instantiate dynamic array Magento

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

Kick me if I'm being silly but some some reason I'm having a heck of time building a dynamic array in magento.

Example:

```
$data = array();

$data[0] = 'test';
$data[1] = 'what';
```

I keep getting an ERROR:
**Notice: Undefined offset:  0**

Any ideas?
Do I need to handle these arrays differently since they are in a class?

Comment: In which file are you attempting to put the code?

Comment: Are you trying to put $data inside a class but outside of a function?

Comment: obviously the error comes from elsewhere ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dropped the following code into a controller action

```
        $data = array();            
        $data[0] = 'test';
        $data[1] = 'what';
        var_dump($data);
```

And got the following Notice free output

```
array
  0 => string 'test' (length=4)
  1 => string 'what' (length=4)
```

So your problem is elsewhere.  There's probably somewhere else in your code where you're referencing

```
    $data[0]
```

in a non-assignment operator way.  That's why you're getting the Notice.